# Output test build to dist

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I build my Angular 9 application in a Jenkins pipeline. Two of the steps are:

- `npm run test:prod` which resolves to `node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --prod`; and
- `npm run build:prod` which resolves to `node --max_old_space_size=4096 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod`.

Doing this causes (of course) two Angular builds, which takes about 2 minutes each in my case. So testing and building my application takes more than 4 minutes.

Is there a way to output the build result from the test run? In my opinion this would be perfectly valid, because the build should be the same as the production output (otherwise the unit tests would be useless).

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely certain but I don't think you want to do that.

`ng test --prod` probably bundles the production build of the application AND the `.spec.ts` files to be tested and runs the tests.

`ng build --prod` bundles the production build of the application and just that.

So let's say, `ng test --prod` has the production build as you want it, how would you remove the `.spec.ts` bundles?

Also, `ng build --prod` and `ng test --prod` use two different TypeScript configurations (tsconfig.json).